# Magento isSalable returning nothing

Tags: php, magento

I ran into a problem somehow where a product that is in stock and has a quantity of over 400000 is saying it is not salable. Or rather isSalable is not returning a value.

I pulled up the function to take a look and I noticed something odd.

Here is the function:

```
public function isSalable(){
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_is_salable_before', array(
        'product'   => $this
    ));
    $salable = $this->isAvailable();
    $object = new Varien_Object(array(
        'product'    => $this,
        'is_salable' => $salable
    ));
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_is_salable_after', array(
        'product'   => $this,
        'salable'   => $object
    ));
    // echo "variable: ".$salable."<br />object: ".$object->getIsSalable();

    return $object->getIsSalable();
}
```

The commented echo was to see the value before it was put into the object and the value retrieved from the object. On the problem product I get:

```
variable: 1
object:
```

On other products they both come back as 1.

Does anyone know what would cause this to happen?

**---EDIT---**

Sorry, the function returns `$object->getIsSalable()`, not `$salable`.

This is on **Magento Enterprise 1.12**

I realize now that the object call is returning false. The effects of posting this at the end of the day.

I moved the echo to before the event dispatch and both came back as 1 so i looked into the event and tracked down where it is setting it to false.

I tracked it to this function in Enterprise/CatalogEvent:

```
public function applyIsSalableToProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $event = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getEvent();
    echo "<br />".$event->getStatus()."<br />";
    if ($event && in_array($event->getStatus(), array(
                Enterprise_CatalogEvent_Model_Event::STATUS_CLOSED,
                Enterprise_CatalogEvent_Model_Event::STATUS_UPCOMING
    ))) {
        $observer->getEvent()->getSalable()->setIsSalable(false);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

If I echo `$event->getStatus()` outside the if, the problem product gives a status of closed, and other products throw an error because $event doesn't exist.

What is causing the difference?

**---EDIT 2---**

I've found that the closed is coming from the product event.

```
$event = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getEvent();
```

I went back to `isSalable()` and added `print_r($this->getEvent()->getData());` after the object creation and got this:

```
Array([event_id] => 3 [category_id] => 12 [date_start] => 2012-11-28 09:54:00 [date_end] => 2012-11-29 09:54:00 [display_state] => [sort_order] => [status] => closed)
```

Again, normal products come back with an error because there is no event on the product.

Where does this event come from?

I'll keep updating as I make progress.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You are saying that "isSalable is not returning a value" but also that "on the problem product, the variable came back with a value of 1". Looking at the method isSalable() that you posted which returns the variable $salable in the end which you say was 1 on the problem product should therefore return 1 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. There was a catalog event set that was setting the status to close. Deleted the event and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear what the output of your debug statement is, but the only logical conclusion that I can come up with is that it is:

```
variable: 1
object: 0
```

Since `$object` is an object it is passed to the event by reference, therefore if your install has any event listener for the event `catalog_product_is_salable_after`, this could modify the value on that object. Since `isAvailable` returns a bool though, the `$salable` variable itself cannot be modified from inside the event, therefore there isn't much point in modifying the 'salable' field in an event listener, since the value isn't retrieved after the event is fired, thus it will never be returned.

This is all a round about way of saying if in your output the `$salable` variable is 1, the function should return 1.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the return. It's supposed to be `$object->getIsSalable()`. The echo had the variable as 1 but the object call was nothing, just blank.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the problem that isSaleable() always returns false on my products, the problem was that I was getting the collection but didn't add the attribute price to the collection. 
In the isSaleable() function there is a check to make sure the price isn't 0, it needs the price attribute to check that so:

Changing:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->addUrlRewrite();
```

To:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('url_path')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->addUrlRewrite();
```

Did the trick :)